# What's the graph for this periodic function

Tags: graphing-functions

Please show the graph for $-2\pi <t<4\pi$
$$f(t)=e^{-t}$$
$$f(t)=f(t\pm2\pi)$$

Is there an online plotter for periodic functions?

Comment: I believe you mean $-2\pi <t\leq 2\pi$...?

Comment: The problem is from an exam that I just wrote. Our task was to draw the function and then transform the periodic function to a Fourier series. It's $e^{-t}$ and $-2\pi < t < 4\pi$

Comment: Obviously, there's some mistake there. Since $f(0) \ne f(2\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it this way: At first $f(t)$ is only defined for $-2\pi<t\leq2\pi$. This would just be the normal graph of $f(t)$, exept you only draw the part within the given interval. If you want to know the value of $f(t)$ for a $t$ outside this interval, you use the fact that $f(t)=f(t\pm2\pi)$, so you can go back with steps of $2\pi$ untill you are back in the original interval. This  is how you get to know the values of $f(t)$ on all of $\mathbb R$.

As for the graph, it will be that little piece of $e^{-t}$ on $(-2\pi,2\pi]$. Only there will be a great number of these segments and they're all at a fixed distance of their direct predecessor.

Comment: I've use the interval $(-2\pi,2\pi]$, because this makes more sense to me. I've assumed you made a typ-o. Please check your question for this.